# Can a two Entities of the same Kind have the same ID if the parent is different?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I know that datastore will auto generate a unique ID for root Entities. But what about Entities of the same Kind that have different Parents?

Will datastore auto generate unique IDs for Entities for the same Kind with different parents (of same Kind)? e.g. `User->Post`. Could two different Users conceivably each have a Post with the same ID?

Comment: Uhm the answer to that is obviously yes. I thought you wanted to ask whether allocateId will give you unique ids even if the parent is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a JUnit test for you. It uses lombok, but you can write out the getters and setters as well.

```
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;
import com.googlecode.objectify.*;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Parent;
import com.googlecode.objectify.util.Closeable;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;

public class IdAllocationTest {
    @Entity
    public static class ChildEntity {
        @Parent
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private Ref<ParentEntity> parent;
        @Id
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private Long id;
    }

    @Entity
    public static class ParentEntity {
        @Id
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private Long id;
    }

    public static class OfyService {
        static {
            try {
                ObjectifyService.register(ChildEntity.class);
                ObjectifyService.register(ParentEntity.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Could not initialized objectify service." + e.toString());
            }
        }

        public static Objectify ofy() {
            return ObjectifyService.ofy();
        }

        public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
            return ObjectifyService.factory();
        }
    }

    private static LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
    private static Closeable objectifyBegin;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass(){
        helper.setUp();
        objectifyBegin = ObjectifyService.begin();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass(){
        objectifyBegin.close();
        helper.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testIdAllocation() {
        Ref<ParentEntity> parent1 = Ref.create(Key.create(ParentEntity.class, 1L));
        Ref<ParentEntity> parent2 = Ref.create(Key.create(ParentEntity.class, 2L));

        ChildEntity childEntity1 = new ChildEntity();
        childEntity1.setParent(parent1);
        childEntity1.setId(1L);

        ChildEntity childEntity2 = new ChildEntity();
        childEntity2.setParent(parent2);
        childEntity2.setId(1L);

        OfyService.ofy().save().entities(childEntity1, childEntity2).now();

        List<Key<ChildEntity>> keys = OfyService.ofy().load().type(ChildEntity.class).keys().list();
        // If overwriting occurred it would be only a single entity
        Assert.assertEquals(keys.size(), 2);
        for (Key<ChildEntity> child : keys) {

            System.out.println("Key( " +
                    "Key('" + child.getParent().getKind() + "'," + child.getParent().getId() + "), " +
                    "'" + child.getKind() + "', " + child.getId() + ")");
        }

        while(true) {
            KeyRange<ChildEntity> keyRangeParent1 = OfyService.factory().allocateIds(parent1, ChildEntity.class, 100);
            KeyRange<ChildEntity> keyRangeParent2 = OfyService.factory().allocateIds(parent2, ChildEntity.class, 100);

            for (Key<ChildEntity> keyParent1 : keyRangeParent1) {
                for (Key<ChildEntity> keyParent2 : keyRangeParent2) {
                    System.out.println(keyParent1.getId() + ", " + keyParent2.getId());
                    Assert.assertTrue(keyParent1.getId() != keyParent2.getId());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the devserver, the output of this unit test starts like this

```
Key( Key('ParentEntity',1), 'ChildEntity', 1)
Key( Key('ParentEntity',2), 'ChildEntity', 1)
1, 101
1, 102
1, 103
1, 104
1, 105
```

Which proofs two things:

1. Same Id with different ancestor is possible
2. The behaviour on the devserver is that ids won't collide (they seem to use the same counter). Basically this proofs that we can't proof a thing by looking at the devserver, but the code could (theoretically) be run on a live system.

**Warning:** Please don't deploy this code. There's a potenially endless loop in there and the chances of an actual hit are quite small. One would have to drastically increase the number of allocated ids and keep the allocated ids of one parent for comparison. Even then you'd hit the DeadlineExceeded and OutOfMemory exception long before you've tested all allocatedIds.

*Summary:*
Unless someone from Google can enlightens us on how the id allocation works, there isn't much we can find out. A quick look in the [Datastore implementation](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java) shows that an allocation is a request to the datastore thus there's no code that could be analyzed to dig deeper.

I guess we'll just have to trust that the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities) is right, when it says

> The only way to avoid such conflicts is to have your application obtain a block of IDs with the methods DatastoreService.allocateIds() or AsyncDatastoreService.allocateIds().
>   The Datastore's automatic ID generator will keep track of IDs that
>   have been allocated with these methods and will avoid reusing them for
>   another entity, so you can safely use such IDs without conflict.

about the id allocation methods.

Comment: Nice job. The rest of the last quote you posted says "The only way to avoid such conflicts is to have your application obtain a block of IDs with the methods DatastoreService.allocateIds() or AsyncDatastoreService.allocateIds(). " Both those methods are from the `com.google.appengine.api.datastore` namespace. Hopefully that statement also applies to the `allocateId()/allocateIds()`  methods in the    `com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory` namespace that both you and I use.

Comment: They do since Objectify is mostly a wrapper for the Datastore API that does the object relational mapping (thus the name objectify)

Comment: Do you suppose it is OK to have methods that save an Entity to the datastore and let it auto-generate an ID and other methods that allocate an ID first with the same Kind and save it to the datastore? Does `allocateId()` by definition make sure it doesn't give you an ID already in the datastore even if it didn't make it? Just wondering because in some API methods where you use transactions you might need to allocate an ID.

Comment: Yes. Automatically assigned IDs and IDs from `allocateId()` will **not** collide.

Comment: The dev server works differently than the actual datastore. I found a situation in my own app where two instances of a kind with different parents end up with the same id on the actual datastore, but different ids on the dev server.

Comment: @EdwinHoogerbeets Good to know. So the same id can occur within the same kind if the ancestor is different. That actually makes sense because we should always look at the whole key and not just the id of a kind. Did you allocate the Ids with `allocateId()` or were the ids automatically assigned?

Comment: @konqi my app allows datastore to allocate them automatically, so the datastore chooses the same Id by itself