# Objectify, setting entity id/name manually - use cases

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, anti-patterns

I want to implement a friendship structure in my app. My first approach was to create Friendship entity with following structure

```
@Entity Friendship{
    @Id Long id;
    @Parent User<Key> userA;
    @Index User<Ref> userB;
}
```

Every friendship is represented by two Friendship entities, one for each user. This works fine for simple cases, but now i want to run query `find user's friends with name foo`, so I'm adding `@Index String userBName` in Friendship, and setting it while creating an entity. But this value needs to be updated every time userB changes his name, plus it's additional column in index and that is a thing that I want to avoid.
So i came up with another approach: remove `userB` property and set Friendship `id` to `@Id` of User that would be referenced by `userB`. Then I would be able to query for User with given name, create Key based on it's `@Id` and filter Friendship by parent and created Key.

```
@Entity Friendship{
    @Id Long id;
    @Parent User<Key> userA;
}
Key<User> userA;
Key<User> userB;
Friendship friendshipA;
Friendship friendshipB;

CreateFriendship(){
    friendshipA.setId(userB.getId());
    friendshipA.setUserA(userA);

    friendshipB.setId(userA.getId());
    friendshipB.setUserA(userB);
}
```

Now my question is: is this a correct use case of manual setting entity id? I think it will work since Key is created by parent, type and id. But on the other hand I don't think this creates logical connection between entities.
Is this a good approach, or am I creating an anti pattern?

Comment: Are your UserA and UserB entity group owners (i.e. they have no parent entities)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of your `User` entities (i.e. the `Friendship` parent entities) can have parents themselves then their IDs are **not** guaranteed to be unique, so they can't be used as `Friendship` (or any other entity kind) IDs. You'd have to use the entire user key, not just the ID, like in your pre-proposal code.

Otherwise it looks OK to me. See also [re-using an entity's ID for other entities of different kinds - sane idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954102/re-using-an-entitys-id-for-other-entities-of-different-kinds-sane-idea)

Just pay attention when deleting a `User` entity to always delete all friendships with that user ID for all other users. Leftover such orphan friendships present the risk of undesired "revival" should the corresponding user ID be eventually re-used in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. Yes, User will always be a root entity. I'm aware that parent relationship doesn't involve any form of 'cascade delete', but in the first approach i would have to delete Friendships manually too. My goal is to eliminate denormalized data, such as indexing duplicate userName in Friendship.