# Objectify: How can I have a unique ID across several types?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have a few types that have a common field(Email ID) that I am using as an `@Id`. These types extend from a common type User which has the Email ID field. It is something like below:

```
@Entity
class User{
  @Id
  String emailID;
}

@Entity
@Subclass(index = true)
class UserType1 extends User{

  String otherField;
}


@Entity
@Subclass(index = true)
class UserType2 extends User{

  String otherField;
}
```

Now, I want that every time I insert a subtype of User, the Email ID should remain unique across all these subtypes objects in the datastore. I tested an endpoint for the above types by inserting each of subtypes with the same EmailID and it happened successfully - Objectify shouldn't have allowed the persistence of subtypes with the same ID. As per my understanding, the ultimate uniqueness is ensured by the keys but can't I ensure uniqueness by an Id across just the subtypes especially when ID is in the base class? Is there some way to do it?

**EDIT:**
Although, this is not the solution I was looking for, I have handled this situation by creating a new entity type with {EmailID, Key_Subtype} which worked in ensuring the uniqueness. I just check this entity for existing emailID and I use the key for retrieving the object with another query.

If anyone comes off with a better solution, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

UUID is that what you are looking for. It is generated for each entity. Type does not matter.

https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers

Comment: With Objectify, problem is I will have to run a query per Subtype. I have Email ID already as a unique identifier so I don't require UUID for every type. I just want a way to query all subtypes in 1 query to find out if Email ID property is unique for the new user.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. So, maybe just an enum with user types?

Answer (score 0):

Same `Id` for different entity types is definitely possible at the datastore level, see [re-using an entity's ID for other entities of different kinds - sane idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954102/re-using-an-entitys-id-for-other-entities-of-different-kinds-sane-idea)

The `Id` uniqueness is only guaranteed across entities of **the same kind and with the same parent entity** (the unique entity key is based on a combination of these 3 items). Since your subtypes are actually different entity kinds there is no problem having the same `Id` across these kinds, so subclassing is not the way to achieve what you want.

To have unique `Id`s you need to have a unique entity kind, say `User`. To distinguish the different user types maybe have inside `User` a `type` property which would be a reference to a entity of `UserTypeX` kind containing the info specific to that user type?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have found the "correct" solution - create an `Email` entity that uses the email address as the id and contains a pointer to the appropriate `User` entity. When creating a new `User`/`Email`, always check for pre-existence of the email address in a transaction.

This really isn't any different from using the email address as the id of the `User` directly except that the extra layer of indirection allows users to change their email addresses, which is generally a good idea. The transactional logic is similar either way.

Transactionally looking up & creating an entity with a natural primary key is pretty much the only way of guaranteeing uniqueness in the datastore. It is effective and scalable.