# AppEngine - How to join object to another in one-one relationship using key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, app-engine-ndb

I have two kinds of entity in my model (Consults and Assessment):

```
class Consults(ndb.Model):

# Basic Consult Info (To get started storing a consult in the datastore)

    # Timestamp consult submitted to datastore
    consult_created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    # Consult booking date
    consult_date = ndb.StringProperty()
    # Consult booking time
    consult_time = ndb.StringProperty()
    # Provider booking the consult
    consult_user = ndb.StringProperty()
    # Consult status: (Pending, Completed, Cancelled)
    consult_status = ndb.StringProperty(choices=('Pending','Completed','Cancelled'),default='Pending')

# Patient Info

    # The patient's first name
    patient_first = ndb.StringProperty()
    # The patient's last name
    patient_last = ndb.StringProperty()
    # The patient's email address
    patient_phone = ndb.StringProperty()
    # The patient's phone number
    patient_email = ndb.StringProperty()
    # The patient's age in years
    patient_age = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    # Does the patient agree to emails from JW?
    patient_optin = ndb.BooleanProperty()

# Clinical Info

    # Does the patient use an orthodic?
    clin_ortho = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    # Foot type:(Over Pronated, Moderatly Pronated, Neturtal, Supinated, Orthosis)
    clin_type = ndb.StringProperty(choices=('Over Pronated','Moderately Pronated','Neutral','Supinated','Orthosis'))
    # The measured leangth of the foot
    clin_length = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    # The measured width of the foot    
    clin_width = ndb.IntegerProperty()                          
    # Provider notes - previous injury history
    clin_inj = ndb.TextProperty()                               
    # Provider notes - recommendations on footware
    clin_recom = ndb.TextProperty()                     
    # Regular physical activity [1]
    clin_activ1 = ndb.StringProperty()                          
    # Activity frequency: (daily, weekly) [1]
    clin_freq1 = ndb.StringProperty(choices=('Daily','Weekly'))                                 
    # Regular physical activity [2]
    clin_activ2 = ndb.StringProperty()                          
    # Activity frequency: (daily, weekly) [2]
    clin_freq2 = ndb.StringProperty(choices=('Daily','Weekly'))                             
    # Regular physical activity [3]
    clin_activ3 = ndb.StringProperty()                          
    # Activity frequency: (daily, weekly) [3]
    clin_freq3 = ndb.StringProperty(choices=('Daily','Weekly'))                 

class Assessments(ndb.Model):

# JW Recommendations

    # JW consultant requested - can be overidden by consultant
    assess_consultant = ndb.StringProperty()
    # Consultant notes - general recommendation notes
    assess_notes = ndb.TextProperty()

# Recommended Shoe [1]

    # Product ID/link
    assess_pid1 = ndb.StringProperty()                                          
    # Category
    assess_category1 = ndb.StringProperty()                             
    # Brand
    assess_brand1 = ndb.StringProperty()                        
    # Model
    assess_model1 = ndb.StringProperty()                        
    # Size
    assess_size1 = ndb.StringProperty()                         
    # Width
    assess_width1 = ndb.StringProperty()                            

# Recommended Shoe [2]

    # Product ID/link
    assess_pid2 = ndb.StringProperty()
    # Category
    assess_category2 = ndb.StringProperty()
    # Brand
    assess_brand2 = ndb.StringProperty()
    # Model
    assess_model2 = ndb.StringProperty()
    # Size
    assess_size2 = ndb.StringProperty()
    # Width
    assess_width2 = ndb.StringProperty()

# Recommended Shoe [3]

    # Product ID/link
    assess_pid3 = ndb.StringProperty()                                  
    # Category
    assess_category3 = ndb.StringProperty()                             
    # Brand
    assess_brand3 = ndb.StringProperty()                        
    # Model
    assess_model3 = ndb.StringProperty()                        
    # Size
    assess_size3 = ndb.StringProperty()                         
    # Width
    assess_width3 = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Firstly a Consult is created and put to the datastore. This consult can be viewed with the consults/view-consult page. The url has that consult's key embedded:

```
http://localhost:8080/consults/view-consult?key=aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXIVCxIIQ29uc3VsdHMYgICAgIDIkwkM
```

On this page the user can click a link saying "Add Assessment" that will send them to the consults/insert-assessment page, with the key embedded as before:

```
http://localhost:8080/schedule/insert-assessment?key=aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXIVCxIIQ29uc3VsdHMYgICAgIDIkwkM
```

Question is how do I join these objects in a one-to-one relationship when the user hits submit and posts the Assessment object (every consult has exactly one assessment to attach).

Do you I need to add something to my assessment model?

Also, I then want to display both object's parameters on the view consult page.

**Edit**

```
class ViewConsultPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        consult = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('key')).get()
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/view-consult.html')
        template_values = {
        'consult': consult 
        } 
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
    def post(self):
        jw_consultant = self.request.get("jw_consultant")
        jw_notes = self.request.get("jw_notes")
        pid1 = self.request.get("pid1")
        cat1 = self.request.get("cat1")
        brand1 = self.request.get("brand1")
        model1 = self.request.get("model1")
        size1 = self.request.get("size1")
        width1 = self.request.get("width1")
        pid2 = self.request.get("pid2")
        cat2 = self.request.get("cat2")
        brand2 = self.request.get("brand2")
        model2 = self.request.get("model2")
        size2 = self.request.get("size2")
        width2 = self.request.get("width2")
        pid3 = self.request.get("pid3")
        cat3 = self.request.get("cat3")
        brand3 = self.request.get("brand3")
        model3 = self.request.get("model3")
        size3 = self.request.get("size3")
        width3 = self.request.get("width3")
        assessment = Assessments(id=consult.key.id(),
                                assess_consultant=jw_consultant,
                                assess_notes=jw_notes,
                                assess_pid1=pid1,
                                assess_category1=cat1,
                                assess_brand1=brand1,
                                assess_model1=model1,
                                assess_size1=size1,
                                assess_width1=width1,
                                assess_pid2=pid2,
                                assess_category2=cat2,
                                assess_brand2=brand2,
                                assess_model2=model2,
                                assess_size2=size2,
                                assess_width2=width2,
                                assess_pid3=pid3,
                                assess_category3=cat3,
                                assess_brand3=brand3,
                                assess_model3=model3,
                                assess_size3=size3,
                                assess_width3=width3)
        assessment.put()
```

Comment: Side note: you may want to trim your code snippets to an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For entities in a 1:1 relationship you can use identical key IDs, which, among other advantages, makes cross referencing from one entity to the other a breeze.

See, for example:

- [re-using an entity's ID for other entities of different kinds - sane idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954102/re-using-an-entitys-id-for-other-entities-of-different-kinds-sane-idea)
- 2nd example in [Relation Index Entities and Projections Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523602/relation-index-entities-and-projections-query/42524709#42524709)

For your code example:

- somewhere in `/templates/view-consult.html` you'd pass `consult`'s key string representation `connect_key_string` or even its key id `connect_id` to the post form, so that info is then available in the `post()` request
- in the `post()` method you'd directly use that ID or restore the `connect` entity's key (as in your other post [Linking to entity from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470443/linking-to-entity-from-list/42472890#42472890)) and then get the key's ID:

  ```
  connect_id = int(self.request.get("connect_id"))
  assessment = Assessment(id=connect_id)
  assessment.put()
  ```

  or

  ```
  connect_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('connect_key_string'))
  assessment = Assessment(id=connect_key.id())
  assessment.put()
  ```

Comment: Thanks Dan, just trying to understand how to apply your "re-using an entity" to my specfic context. Is it something like I need two add a property to each model somehow using the KeyProperty ?

Comment: When creating the Assessment entity specify its KeyID to be the same as the corresponding Consult's KeyID: 
`assessment = Assessment(id=consult.key.id())`
`assessment.put()`

Comment: Great - I will give that a try.

Comment: Got the following error  assessment = Assessments(id=consult.key.id(),
NameError: global name 'consult' is not defined.

Comment: Well, you'd have the already created corresponding `Consult` entity in that variable. Check the examples in the references

Comment: It is created for the 'get' but not the 'post'. I have added edit to original post to show my ViewConsultPage request handler.

Comment: I added consult = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('key')).get() under the post and got the error : TypeError: Cannot construct Key reference from incompatible keyword arguments.

Comment: What are the type and value of `self.request.get('key')`? (unrelated: you don't need to do the `.get()` just to obtain the key's ID - unnecessary datastore access)

Comment: When we land on the assessment form page, the key has been passed to that page in the url. eg http://localhost:8080/schedule/insert-assessment?key=aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXIVCxIIQ29uc3VsdHMYgICAgIDIkwkM. how can we insert this key into new Assessment (id). Is this the goal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137096/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-timothyaura).