# Sharding counters with 180 properties

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, sharding

Does it sound bad to have 180 unindexed properties(columns) with Integer/Long type per entity in datastore?

I need to count 6 requests per user saving by day for analytics reasons and I'm doing everything based on the sharding counters article and webcast:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

So basically it's 6 values per day incrementing every new request, so I'm thinking in having:

1 Kind per Month
6 types of analytics * month days = 180

How much is too much in Google Datastore properties?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not a good idea.

Keep in mind that every time you want to update a single property value the *entire* entity will have to be re-written (i.e. retrieved from the datastore, deserialized, updated, re-serialized and re-sent to the datastore). The bigger the entity, the slower the performance.

IMHO it's better to have multiple smaller entities than a big one in such case. It is possible to split a single big entity into multiple smaller ones, efficiently related to each-other - see [re-using an entity's ID for other entities of different kinds - sane idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954102/re-using-an-entitys-id-for-other-entities-of-different-kinds-sane-idea)

Along the same line I believe it's even possible to find a way to encode the day info and the user ID into unique custom key IDs, for easy access. Something like `<userid>_YYMMDD` or just `<userid>_DD`

Comment: However, Google charges for the *number* of entities read and written, not for the *size* of the data read or written.  It would cost 180 times more to read & write 180 entities with 1 field each than it would 1 entity with 180 fields.  Performance vs cost: pick one :)

Comment: @BareNakedCoder Hm, not exactly - the charge is for the number of read/write ops, not the number of entities. So (re)writing a single entity 180 times costs just as much as writing once to 180 different entities.

Comment: Lol!  You are 100% correct.  But I never thought anyone would misinterpret what I said that way.  Obviously when writing an entity, DS would not look in its history logs to see if this entity was written recently and so not bill for the current write.  The key point (that I hope was not lost) is that 180 read/write ops will cost a lot more than just 1 larger op.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder You're right as well, but don't forget the context of this particular question: those 180 properties cannot be updated all at the same time, they're updated at a rate of 6 per day. I'd pick a daily stats entity structure, not a monthly one (and yes, not one with a single counter per entity where your comment would apply).