# NDB query with projection on an attribute used in .IN()

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

Let's say I have a model:

```
class Pet(ndb.Model):
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    owner = ndb.KeyProperty(indexed=True)
```

And I have a list of keys named `owners`. To do a query for `Pet`s I would do:

```
pets = Pets.query(Pets.owner.IN(owners)).fetch()
```

The problem is that this query returns the whole entity.

**How can I do a projected query and get just the owner and the name?**

Or how should I structure the data to just get the name and the owner.

I can do a projection for the `name` but I loose reference from the pet to the owner. And `owner` can't be in the projection.

Comment: It always returns the whole entity (object) by design

Comment: Please clarify your question for me, because if you have a list of keys.You can call `(key).get()` and and it will bring the `entity` which you will choose the propery you want. Also fetching an entity by key is free in app engine!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed, you can't do that with the exact context you mentioned, because you hit one of the [Limitations on projections](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries#Python_Limitations_on_projections):

> - **Properties referenced in an equality (=) or membership (IN) filter cannot be projected.**

Since `owner` is used in a `IN` filter it can't be projected. Since you need the `owner` and you can't project it you'll have to drop the projection and thus you'll always get the entire entity.

One alternative would be to split your entity into 2 peer entities, always into a 1:1 relationship, using the same entity IDs:

```
class PetA(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    owner = ndb.KeyProperty(indexed=True)

class PetB(ndb.Model):
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
```

This way you can do the same query, except on `PetA` kind instead of the original `Pet` and the result you'd get would be the equivalent of the original projection query you were seeking.

Unfortunately this will only work with one or a very few such projection queries for the same entity, otherwise you'd need to split the entity in too many pieces. So you may have to compromise.

You can find more details about the entity splitting in [re-using an entity's ID for other entities of different kinds - sane idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954102/re-using-an-entitys-id-for-other-entities-of-different-kinds-sane-idea)

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea. Thanks. But if the pet would only contain the data I need would you say it's a good idea to only index the `owner`? The name is not necessary, right? No queries for the name

Comment: Indexing `name` is needed only if you want to filter or sort your query results by `name`.