# Google Datastore bulk retrieve data using urlsafe

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

Is there a way in Google DataStore to bulk fetch entities using their urlsafe key values?

I know about `ndb.get_multi([list])` which takes a list of keys and retrieves the entities in bulk which is more efficient. But in our case we have a webpage with a few hundred entities, embedded with the entities urlsafe key values. At first we were only doing operations on single entities, so we were able to use the urlsafe value to retrieve the entity and do the operation without much trouble. Now, we need to change multiple entities at once, and looping on them one by one does not sound like an efficient approach. Any thoughts?

Is there any advantage of using the entities key ID directly (*versus the key urlsafe value*)? `get_by_id()` in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id) does not imply being able to get entities in bulk (takes only one ID).

If the only way to retrieve entities in bulk is using the entities key, yet, exposing the key on the webpage is not a recommended approach, does that mean we're stuck when it comes to bulk operations on a page with a few hundred entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys and the urlsafe strings are exactly in a 1:1 relationship. When you have one you can obtain the other:

```
urlsafe_string = entity_key.urlsafe()
entity_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=urlsafe_string)
```

So if you have a bunch of urlsafe strings you can obtain the corresponding keys and then use `ndb.get_multi()` with those keys to get all entities, modify them as needed then use `ndb.put_multi()` to save them back into the datastore.

As for using IDs - that only works (in a convenient manner) if you do not use entity ancestry. Otherwise to obtain a key you need both the ID and the entity's parent key (or its entire ancestry) - it's not convenient, better use urlsafe strings in this case.

But for entities with no parents (aka root entities in the respective entity groups) the entity keys and their IDs are always in a 1:1 relationship and again you can obtain one if you have the other:

```
entity_key_id = entity_key.id()
entity_key = ndb.Key(MyModel, entity_key_id)
```

So again from a bunch of IDs you can obtain keys to use with `ndb.get_multi()` and/or `ndb.put_multi()`.

Using IDs can have a cosmetic advantage over the urlsafe strings - typically shorter and easier on the eyes when they apear in URLs or in the page HTML code :)

Another advantage of using IDs is the ability to split large entities or to deal in a simpler manner with entities in a 1:1 relationship. See [re-using an entity's ID for other entities of different kinds - sane idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954102/re-using-an-entitys-id-for-other-entities-of-different-kinds-sane-idea)

For more info on keys and IDs see  [Creating and Using Entity Keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys).

Comment: Thanks @Dan Cornilescu a lot for the explanation, so what you are saying is that looping on the urlsafe list and using `entity_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=urlsafe_string)` would not access the datastore, this is basically an ndb class function to convert (_decode_) the urlsafe to a key? after which `ndb.get_multi()` can be used, am I correct?

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I tried it and it worked out beautifully. Another challenge emerged since I was trying to use the async version `ndb.get_multi_async()` which returns a list of futures instead of a single one and `get_result()` does not work on lists. Don't want to loop on the list, yet to figure this one out :D..

Comment: You have to get the results anyways - I presume you use `get_multi*` because you want the entity values.  It's just `entities = [future,get_result() for future in future_list]`, I don't see this as an issue...

Comment: Yes for the values, I'm trying to use async to get a better user experience, so using non blocking datastore calls. Though I don't think it's a major issue in that particular part of the code, as not much is happening before I have to call for the results. Was just looking for a way to bulk retrieve values, instead of loop, a tiny bit of _performance_ concern

Comment: You are retrieving them in bulk. The `.get_result()` loop just ensures that the results for all futures are received. It's normal for async operations.