# Storing user data in Google Cloud Datastore as an Entity Group

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to find the best way to store a user in google datastore (using nodejs). I have the userId and a userData object:

```
userId: "some-random-string"

userData: {
    info: {
        name: "name",
        email: "test@email.com"
    },
    profile: {
        username: "user",
        status: "using"
    },
    stats: {
        stuffDone: 12,
        stuffNotDone: 20
    },
    inventory: {
        money: 100,
        items: ["first", "second", "third"]
    }
}
```

I know I can store all this as a single entity but would it be worth it to split it up into an entity group if I will be updating all the nested objects separately (info, profile, stats, inventory).

So I would have the root entity (that probably wouldn't exist):

```
datastore.key(["Users", userId])
```

then I would create 4 children to store the userData:

```
datastore.key(["Users", userId, "UserData", "Info"); --> userData.info
datastore.key(["Users", userId, "UserData", "Profile"); --> userData.profile
datastore.key(["Users", userId, "UserData", "Stats"); --> userData.stats
datastore.key(["Users", userId, "UserData", "Inventory"); --> userData.inventory
```

Only the user would be updating the data so contention should not be an issue. Once the user is created I wouldn't need to update more than one child at a time.

So say the stats is updated every minute, I can just update it directly with the key:

```
datastore.key(["Users", userId, "UserData", "Stats");
```

Would this be the best practice to split it up instead of rewriting the whole user object to a single entity and have to rewrite all the indexes?

---

With the entity group I can still query all the user data at once with:

```
query = datastore.createQuery().hasAncestor(datastore.key(["Users", userId]));
```

Then I would just need to process it to get it back into the userData object above. I would only need to do this once when the user logs in, all other times I would need to get user data it would only be a single child and I could just get the child by key.

---

If I shouldn't be using an entity group like this then I could do the same thing by storing each part of the user in separate entities like:

```
datastore.key(["UsersInfo", userId); --> userData.info
datastore.key(["UsersProfile", userId); --> userData.profile
datastore.key(["UsersStats", userId); --> userData.stats
datastore.key(["UsersInventory", userId); --> userData.inventory
```

Then I could still update them individually but I think would be more taxing to get all the data since I would need to do 4 queries instead of an ancestor query.

---

Would these entity groups or multiple entities be necessary if I am only updating the userData.stats and userData.profile around once per minute, or should I just be using a single entity. The stats and profile objects will get bigger than only a couple properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting an entity into multiple related ones based on the property update patterns may be a good idea, especially for large entities - to avoid unnecessarily re-writing the entire entity when just a portion of it changes (with the associated increase in the duration of the update of the entity itself and of all its related indexes. See related [re-using an entity's ID for other entities of different kinds - sane idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954102/re-using-an-entitys-id-for-other-entities-of-different-kinds-sane-idea)

Placing all the entity "pieces" into the same entity group - which, as you observed, allows you to make ancestor queries to retrieve the user data, is OK as long as you respect the max 1 write/second per entire entity group. Just double-check if you can safely assume that the query results come in a specific order, otherwise you may need to take steps to ensure each result goes to the right object.

Using separate, non-ancestor related entity "pieces" allows a higher overall write rate than the split with ancestor: max 1 write/second per each entity. And technically you don't need to do 4 *queries* to retrieve the entities, but 4 key *lookup* operations, see [Retrieving an entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#datastore-datastore-lookup-nodejs).

But splitting the entity can also increase your datastore costs: the single read/write operation for a single entity will be multiplied by the number of "pieces" in which the entity was split - in your case 4 if you read/write all of them together.

So you'll have to balance these pros and cons in the context of your application.