# Redirect loading old content?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

a little bit of a weird issue. To simplify the problem for explanation purposes. A user goes onto /Total page and gets the count of the records in the datastore with "steve" as the name, at the moment there is 2, he can then presses increment and the user gets redirected to /Increment so another record is added into the nbd, the user is then once again redirected to /Total however it still shows 2! If he simply refreshes the page, it then shows 3. I assume it's because the redirect back to /Total happens before the entity is fully committed into the datastore? If not, here's the code, please let me know what's wrong. Thank you!

```
    PYTHON:
    @app.route("/Total", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def total():
     data = Logins.query(Logins.name == "steve").count()
    return render_template('Total.html', count=count)

    @app.route("/Increment", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def incre():
     new_data = oAuthLogins()
     new_data.name = "steve"
     new_data.put()
    return redirect(url_for('total'))

    Total.html:
    {{count}}
    <a href={{url_for('incre')}}> Increment! </a>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add which datastore you are using, and if it's being run in some type of cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a bunch of reasons: slow db update (eventually consistent), caching, etc.

But, is this a good user experience?

If a user sees a number (2) then presses increment, but that record has changed, is it better to show the user the number they expect (3), or the actual number (which may be much higher than 3 by the time they click increment)?

For UX, I would think the user should see the number 3. He/she can always see the latest number with another refresh.

With that in mind, you solve this by changing the `/increment` call to be done via AJAX and simply increment the number on the front end when you get a 200 response.

Answer (score 0):

You're obtaining the count from a (`Logins` kind) query which is always eventually consistent unless it's an ancestor query.

You could display the correct count if you transform the method of getting it into a strongly consistent one, for example by storing it in a property of the user entity which you can always obtain by key lookup (or some other equivalent entity kind always in a 1-to-1 relationship with the user entity, see [re-using an entity's ID for other entities of different kinds - sane idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954102/re-using-an-entitys-id-for-other-entities-of-different-kinds-sane-idea))

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate the issue and it worked for me. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but here is [my example code in GitHub](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Entities-Python/flaskEntitiesRedirect.py).

When running the code follow these steps:

1. Navigating to localhost:8080 will print Hello World
2. Navigate to localhost:8080/add for the first time to enter the first value in entity. (Will add number 2)
3. Go to the Entities in the GCP page and get the id from the record
4. Replace that id with the one in the code `ENTITY_KEY`
5. Navigate to localhost:8080/get will print the number saved in the entity
6. Navigate to localhost:8080/update will get that number, add 1 to that number and will save the number again.
7. After that it will automatically redirect to localhost:8080/get and will show you the updated value in the entity